# How to show content based on the URL?

Tags: javascript, ajax, url

unfortunately, I have no idea how you call this and had no success finding an answer to my question. Basically, I have built a JS application where the user enters a name and the application will then fetch and process data from an API based on that name.

What I want to do now is that if someone goes to http://www.mywebsite.com/NAME, the data will be fetched/processed for NAME. I know how it works with PHP (xxx.php?name=NAME) but if possible I don't want to use PHP here.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the server language side then.

Comment: I have just used plain JS and some PHP for the AJAX request and caching

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is by using `URL Rewrite`. This does not require any coding in JS or server-side language. This can be done on most server softwares but the method is different depending on what server (IIS, Apache, nginx, etc.) you're using.

Here's [an article about URL Rewriting](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/) to help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

For JavaScript you could use the location object.

```
var url =  window.location.href;

var param = url.replace('http://www.mywebsite.com/', '');
```

Look at Backbone routers for a more organised way of handling params in JavaScript.

http://backbonejs.org/#Router